# Where does the ISO C11 standard state that comparing two pointers that do not point to the same array is undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c11

Where does the ISO C11 standard state that comparing two pointers (with `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) that do not point to the same array is undefined behavior?

Comment: Notably, you can dodge the UB by casting both pointers to `uintptr_t` then compare. Then the outcome would be merely implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [6.5.8p5 from C11 draft](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5) is pretty clear:

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**

That "other case" is for example a case where two pointers point to different arrays.

Note that there is still ongoing work about [pointer provenance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2263.htm) and hopefully future standard will clear the edge cases.

Comment: Of course that's for `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=` comparisons, as requested.  For `==` and `!=`, you've got more latitude: the two pointers *can* point to different objects, and one or both can be null.

Comment: [§6.5.9 Equality operators ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p6): _Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space._ (There's a footnote 109 to chase too).

Comment: The only way a future standard can ever resolve edge cases if it acknowledges the existence of a dialect based upon the clang/gcc execution model, which eliminates many of the behavioral guarantees in the Standard, and a dialect based on a "real-machine" execution model based on a version of the Standard which nuked 6.2.6, but allowed compilers to assume that operations on lvalues of *seemingly-unrelated* lvalues of different types would not alias, but recognized that an access via pointer which is *visibly freshly derived* from something of another type is an access to that other object...

Comment: ...and that the aliasing rule is only applicable to objects accessed within the same context (with the size of the context being limited by the compiler's ability to see pointer derivation).  The clang/gcc dialect may be fine for some purposes if it were accurately specified, but the clang/gcc execution models cannot handle all the edge cases of the C Standard, and the authors have come too far to accept that edge cases they don't want to handle aren't defects in the Standard, but were instead were intended to ensure that compilers adopted a reasonable execution model that could handle them.